# Возможно ли заставить окно в macOS при переходе между пространствами (spaces) вести себя как дефолтный picture in picture?

Tags: objective-c, swift, macos, cocoa

Имею ввиду, заставить его перестать пропадать. Отвязать его от пространств в принципе или что-то вроде того, дабы оно было "поверх" них, что ли. И при пролистывании не уходило вместе с одним, появляясь потом на другом, а так и оставалось на своем месте, невзирая на смену пространств.

Поверх всех окон `.floatingWindow`, включая полноэкранные `application is agent`, а так же отображение на всех пространствах `.canJoinAllSpaces` и нулевая реакция на expose `.stationary` (в оригинале, полагаю, `.ignoresCycle`, но в моем случае так) сделано. Интересует лишь описанное в первом абзаце.

Comment: надо чтобы оно оставалось, когда приложение сворачивается или в рамках работы приложения?

Comment: @MaxMikheyenko смутно понимаю что имеется ввиду под "чтобы оно оставалось, когда приложение сворачивается"... потому, видимо, в рамках работы.

Comment: picture in picture, который вы приводите в пример, работает даже если приложение свернуть и выйти на home экран телефона. вам это надо или?

Comment: @MaxMikheyenko о, прошу прощения, не указал в самом вопросе, только тег поставил. Речь, разумеется, о macOS.